# rails- what value to use for type column? (STI)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, single-table-inheritance, sti

Given a table of users:

```
create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :email
  t.string :website
  t.string :type
end

Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
```

and subscribers that inherit from User

```
Class Subscriber < User
```

What actual value should I use for the type column when inserting a Subscriber?

Comment: Hello! Looks like you have an answer. If it works for you, upvote it and mark it accepted by the check mark. Otherwise, edit/clarify your question or submit your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Rails will automatically save the name of the class in the type column using `object#class.name`.

You can alter this behaviour with the `inheritance_column` class method to set the column where you want to store the class name, or set it to nil if you prefer to disable the behaviour.